# Explain this javascript

Tags: javascript

Could anyone please explain what the code below does, especially point 1 and 2:

1)

```
(function (carWeb) {    
})(carWeb || (carWeb = {}));
```

**Update**
2) why is the function below declared inside IIFE, and GridView is used four times

```
 function GridView() {            
        }
```

// usercontrols.gridview.js

```
var carWeb;
(function (carWeb) {
    carWeb.GridView = (function () {

        function GridView() {            
        }        
        GridView.init = function (gridSelector, threeGridButtonSelector) {
            GridView.gridSelector = gridSelector;            
            threeGridButtonSelector.on("click",  this.setThree);                     
        };

        return GridView;
    })();

})(carWeb || (carWeb = {}));
carWeb.GridView.init($("#top.items"), $("#grid-view-grid")));
```

**Update**

Any link would be appreciated.

Why is the question put on hold? **Please Vote to reopen the post, and upvote the post**

Comment: thats a common way to namespace modules.

Comment: It add the GridView submodule to the carWeb module.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight No : it ensures the module exists.

Comment: @dystroy yeah i just realized that, thought it was a `==`, which would mean nothing.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight @dystroy the `var carWeb; before it sort of does make it useless in a way. Basically if it was defined before that var is going to blow it away. :)

Comment: When a function is declared beetwen parentheses and followed by a pair of parentheses, it runs in the moment it's declared:

    (function (w) {return w;})(window);

The "or"  `||`  check if the variable `carWeb` is null, if so it assigns an empty object `{}`

    carWeb || (carWeb = {})

Comment: @epascarello I don't get what you mean with your comment. How the var keyword is going to blow away the module ? For example [this code perfectly works](https://github.com/Canop/SpaceBullet/blob/master/src/Mission.js).

Comment: Thank all of you for your answer. Please vote it to reopen the question.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto Could you kindly explain the second point, i.e. why  function GridView() {} is declared within two functions.

Comment: tried my best to explain everything here http://jsfiddle.net/GzcFQ/1/ ... hope it helps

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto Thank you for your comments. Can I put questions on  your code, regarding the GridView nameing?

Comment: of course you can ... anytime!

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto I added a question regarding renaming GridView to GridView2 to improve my understanding of the code.

Comment: you should not rename it because it's is global so it might be used somewhere else in the code. If so renaming will break your code.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto I don't want to change it. The reason is because I  want to know if it means the SAME object, to make sure I understand the syntax. So might I say that the four lines all refer to the same object, and will work purely based on that script. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: When a funcion is declared like this `function a(){}` it is global and when it is declared like this `var a = function(){}` it is local;

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto Thank you for your comments. Might I ask you questions regarding the GridView usage. Please refer to the link   http://jsfiddle.net/GzcFQ/5/, on which I post the questions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Answers: http://jsfiddle.net/GzcFQ/6/ . If you feel like you can mail me at rafaelcastrocouto from gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It adds the GridView submodule to the carWeb module, while

- ensuring the carWeb module exists (if carWeb isn't defined then the `(carWeb = {})` statement defines it)
- that if the script is minified, the carWeb variable name can be minified  (but as the variable is defined just before with a `var` statement, this isn't necessary)
- that the variables used for this module are private and don't pollute the global namespace, using [the IIFE pattern](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

This approach is common because if you have many submodules defined in different files, the order of the file isn't important and you can add or remove files (i.e. submodules) depending on your needs.

Another less verbose way to write it (my usual solution) would have been :

```
var carWeb = carWeb || {}
(function(){
   carWeb.GridView = ...
})();
```

[Example](https://github.com/Canop/SpaceBullet/blob/master/src/Mission.js)

Comment: Can the downvoter explain me the error I made.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please vote it to reopen the question.

Comment: Could you kindly explain the second point, i.e. why function GridView() {} is declared within two functions

Comment: @Pingpong It's called an IIFE (see the link I gave). The function call creates a scope and lets you use variables without polluting the outer scope.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have a read on the links, and mark it as answer if it is. Thanks again.

Comment: I read the article. It explains IIFE. But I cannot understand my second questions in the post. Could you please elaborate on it?

Comment: Yet, the inner IEFE seems totally superfluous to me…

Comment: @Bergi If the code is so small, yes. I supposed this was part of a bigger code.